# I'm new using Knockout js, I try to show a list and I get the following error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5

Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function(){return lista }"

----------Codigo----------------

```
$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(modelView);
    modelView.viewCourses();
});
var modelView = {
    Courses: ko.observableArray([]),
    viewCourses: function () {
        var thisObj = this;
        try {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/ListaConcepto',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (data) {
                    thisObj.lista(data); 
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert(err.status + " : " + err.statusText);
                }
            });
        } catch (e) {
            window.location.href = '/Home/Index/';
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Do you have a binding like that in your html?  Knockout foreach bindings should simply be `<div data-bind="foreach: lista"> ...markup to foreach over...</div>`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code that is posted `thisObj.lista(data);` `lista` does not exist on thisObj.  it needs to be added.

```
$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(modelView);
    modelView.viewCourses();
});
var modelView = {
    Courses: ko.observableArray([]),
    viewCourses: function () {
        var thisObj = this;
        thisObj.lista = ko.observableArray(); // adding this line should make it work.
        try {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/ListaConcepto',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (data) {
                    thisObj.lista(data); 
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert(err.status + " : " + err.statusText);
                }
            });
        } catch (e) {
            window.location.href = '/Home/Index/';
        }
    }
};
```